# D3: Updating Fill Color of Inline SVGs

Tags: d3.js

I'm having some trouble updating (enter/update/exit) the fill color of several inline SVG Paths.

```
<svg>
<g id="section11">
<path  id="section11p" d="m 431.78572,404.50506 0,36.875 20,-0.0893 22.14285,3.66072 8.92858,-38.48215 -7.5,-1.60714 z"/>
</g>

<g id="section10">
<path  id="section10p" d="m 476.792,445.13425 8.83884,-38.38579 19.31917,6.43972 21.2132,11.23795 14.77348,9.21764 -21.97082,33.71384 -28.158,-16.66752 z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I used the code from this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ybAj5/6/) to successfully (initially) color all of my inline SVG paths:

```
var colour = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 20])
        .range(["lightgreen", "darkgreen"]);

 dataset1.forEach(function(d){ //d is of form [id,value]
   d3.select("g#"+d[0]) //select the group matching the id
     .datum(d) //attach this data for future reference
     .selectAll("path, polygon")
     .datum(d) //attach the data directly to *each* shape
     .attr("fill", d?colour(d[1]):"lightgray");
});
```

And here is the dataset I've used:

```
var dataset1 = [["section10", 3],
                ["section11", 11],   
                ["section13", 19]];
```

But I would like to incorporate these two datasets:

```
var dataset2 = [["section10", 0],
                ["section11", 11],   
                ["section13", 15]];

var dataset3 = [["section10", 1],
                ["section11", 3],   
                ["section13", 18]];
```

Using this dropdown menu:

```
 <div class ="fixed"><select id = "opts">
    <option value="dataset1" selected="selected">2012 Cohort</option>
    <option value="dataset2">2013 Cohort</option>
    <option value="dataset3">2014 Cohort</option>
 </select></div>
```

I understand I need to encapsulate the process about within an enter/update/exit process with something like this:

```
 function updateLegend(newData) {

    // bind data
    var appending = d3.selectAll('g')
            .data(newData);

    // add new elements
    appending.enter().append('g');

    // update existing elements
    appending.transition()
            .duration(0)
            .style("fill", function(d,i){return colour(i);});

    // remove old elements
    appending.exit().remove();

}

// generate initial legend
updateLegend(ds2);

// handle on click event
d3.select('#opts')
        .on('change', function() {
            var newData = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
            updateLegend(newData);
        });
```

But its tough because I feel that all of the examples I've seen perform the update on SVGs which were created with d3, not custom SVGs created and pasted into the html page from Inkscape (an opensource SVG software).

I feel I'm very close to the solution and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an "enter", "update" and "exit" selection for this. Just pass the value of `dataset` as an argument.

Also, you don't need to bind data. You just need this:

```
data.forEach(function(d){ //d is of form [id,value]
    d3.select("#"+d[0]) //select the group matching the id
        .attr("fill", colour(d[1]));
});
```

Check the demo:

```js
var colour = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 20])
        .range(["lightgreen", "darkgreen"]);
    
var datasets = {dataset1: [["section10", 0],
                ["section11", 11]],
        dataset2:[["section10", 1],
                ["section11", 2]],
        dataset3:[["section10", 17],
                ["section11", 19]],
        dataset4:[["section10", 2],
                ["section11", 19]]
        };
     
        
d3.select('#opts').on('change', function() {
            var value = d3.select(this).property('value');
      var newData = datasets[value];
            reColor(newData);
        });
    
function reColor(data){
data.forEach(function(d){ //d is of form [id,value]
   d3.select("#"+d[0]) //select the group matching the id
     .attr("fill", colour(d[1]));
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
 <div class ="fixed"><select id = "opts">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="dataset1">2013 Cohort</option>
    <option value="dataset2">2014 Cohort</option>
  <option value="dataset3">2015 Cohort</option>
  <option value="dataset4">2016 Cohort</option>
 </select></div> 
<svg width="300" height="300">
<g id="section11">
<path  id="section11p" d="m 31.78572,104.50506 0,36.875 20,-0.0893 22.14285,3.66072 8.92858,-38.48215 -7.5,-1.60714 z"/>
</g>

<g id="section10">
<path  id="section10p" d="m 76.792,145.13425 8.83884,-38.38579 19.31917,6.43972 21.2132,11.23795 14.77348,9.21764 -21.97082,33.71384 -28.158,-16.66752 z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can I use this strategy if I have four total cohorts (4 total datasets)? Eventually I want to be able to change the color based not just on the Cohort year, but also on attributes about the specific cohorts, so I'll need another drop-down menu - Could I employ this strategy for that too?

Comment: @gsol Regarding your first question, check the new demo: I'm using an object now, and the bracket notation to access the datasets (don't use `eval`). Regarding your second question: this is too broad for answering here. Post another question, explaining better your problem.